# File transfer over XMPP fail: could not establish socket with any provided SOCKS5 stream host

Tags: proxy, xmpp

I have a server XMPP, prosody. It works fine for chat and audio/video calls.
But I have problems with file transfer. I have configured proxy65 and turn_external with coturn.
All ports used by coturn and are open.
proxy65_ports = {7777} and that port is open too.
What's the problem here?

In prosody.log:

```
May 30 07:06:05 s2soutd18310    info    Outgoing s2s stream chat.my-domain.com->turn.my-domain.com closed: connection-timeout
May 30 07:06:05 s2soutd18310    info    Sending error replies for 2 queued stanzas because of failed outgoing connection to turn.my-domain.com
```

In my client (aTalk for Adroid):

```
An error occurred while transfering file from test@chat.my-domain.com
Could not establish socket with any provided SOCKS5 stream host.
SOCKS5 Stream Host: test@chat.my-domain.com/DOVie-F6[IP-addres:39515] Exception: 'java.io.IOException: ExecutionException while SOCKS5 client attempting to connect to SOCKS5 Stream Host: test@chat.my-domain.com/DOVie-F6[IP-addres:39515]',
SOCKS5 Stream Host: proxy.my-domain.com[proxy.my-domain.com:7777] Exception: 'java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException', SOCKS5 Stream Host: test@chat.my-domain.com/DOVie-F6[IP-addres:3915] Exception: 'java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException'
```